# Is it stable to use arithmetic in a ctor's initialization list?

Tags: c++, constructor

Is it stable to use something like this in a class's ctor initialization list during implicit assignment (no operators are overloaded):

```
class C{
   public:
      C(int _var): var(_var), i(var*var) 
        {} 
   private:
      int var;
      int i;
};
```

I'm getting some eratic results, why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

You might want to get rid of the initialization order dependency, and write:

```
  C(int _var): var(_var), i(_var*_var)
```

Basically, by making i depend on var, you must ensure that var is declared before i in the class.

Similarly, you can initialize something in C that is defined (and initialized) in a parent class, because the parent will be constructed before C.

Best practices dictate that you be aware of the above, and avoid situations that obfuscate any of that - maybe document i's dependence on var, so that the next programmer (maybe yourself) doesn't introduce an initialization order issue.

Comment: I want to stress your second sentence: `var` must be declared before `i` in the class _definition_. Not in the initializer list (which doesn't matter).

Answer (score 5):

That code has defined meaning, assuming the multiplication doesn't overflow.

Be aware that it relies critically on the fact that `var` is defined before `i` in the class (order in the initializer list is irrelevant, all that matters is the order the members themselves are defined). Otherwise `i` would be initialized using the *unitialized* data member `var`.

But if you're getting erratic behavior with exactly that code, then the bug lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is safe, but in this case you have to be careful. You are using `var` and not `_var`, so you have to be sure `var` is constructed before `i`. This is the case here, since the members are constructed in the order of their declaration (in this case `var`, `i`), which may be different from the order of their appearance in the initializer list.

So in this case it works. It would also work in this case:

```
C(int _var):  i(var*var), var(_var)
```

but not in this:

```
class C{
   public:
      C(int _var): var(_var), i(var*var) 
        {} 
   private:
      int i;
      int var;
};
```

But of course, to be always on the safe side, you could just use `_var`:

```
C(int _var):  var(_var), i(_var*_var)
```

Comment: That worked! so the order of initialization in a ctor depends on the variables' order of declaration in the class prototype? That makes sense!

Comment: @user965369 That is the reason you should also list them in this order in the initializer list (which you did), to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @user965369: You should turn on your compiler warnings (-Wall on gcc, \W3 on VC++), warning about an incorrectly ordered initializer list is common and will help you realize those mistakes earlier.